# AWS getSignedUrl using Lambda function's Role policy, instead of provided credentials

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Inside a lambda function, I am trying to generate a presigned url to an s3 object. I am using [getSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/functions/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.getSignedUrl.html) from @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner. The code snippet to generate the URL is as follows:

```
const s3Client=new S3Client({
                region:region,
                Credentials:{
                    accessKeyId:accessKey, //Temporary Access key from Cognito Identity Pool
                    secretAccessKey:secretKey //Temporary Secret from Cognito Identity pool
                }
              });

              const bucketName=process.env.ASSET_STORE;
              const objectKey=`${requestAssetId}/${requestAssetId}.${requestAssetIdExtension}`;
              const command = new GetObjectCommand({
                Bucket: bucketName,
                Key: objectKey,
                ExpiresIn: 60
              });

              const presignedURL=await getSignedUrl(s3Client,command,{ expiresIn: 60 });
```

The temporary credentials are generated by the following code snippet:

```
const getCredentialsCommand = new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({
                IdentityId: identityId,
                Logins: {
                    // Use the Cognito User Pool token as the login provider
                    'cognito-idp.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<Pool Id>': idTokenReceived
                  },
                  CustomRoleArn:'arn:aws:iam::<AccountId>:policy/<PolicyName>' //Points to Custom Role which has Get Object access to the said s3 object
              });

              let accessKey='';
              let secretKey='';
              let sessionKey='';
              await cognitoIdentityClient.send(getCredentialsCommand,
                (err,data)=>{
                    if(err){
                        console.error(`Error while retrieving credentials:${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                        throw new ('Access Key Retrieval Error');
                    }else{
                        accessKey=data.Credentials.AccessKeyId;
                        secretKey=data.Credentials.SecretKey;
                        sessionKey=data.Credentials.SessionToken;
                    }
              });
```

The issue is, the presignedUrl generated by this gives access denied exception, unless I add the policy of the custom role here to the lambda function. What I mean is, the policy xyz, that gives GetObject access to the s3 object, if it gets attached to the lambda function, then the presigned url works, else it does not.
This behaviour leads me to believe that the getPresignedUrl function is using the policy attached to the lambda function, rather than the ones associated with the temporary credentials. Is that the case. ? If so, then how to ensure the policy attached to temporary credentials are used?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assumption is correct: you're likely using the Lambda Role. 
This is because the credentials you're providing to the S3 Client aren't recognized as valid, prompting the client to revert to the role's credentials.
When using temporary credentials, the SessionToken must be included in the Credentials object, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/credentials.html#sessiontoken).

> **SessionToken**: The token that users must pass to the service API to use the temporary credentials.